# Move a window when a window moves?

Tags: java, javafx

I have

```
for (Window w : Window.getWindows()) {
    if (w.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Main Editor")) {

    }
}
```

The Main Editor window has 2 windows called "Toolbar" and "Browser" (Don't worry about the names)

It's sort of like how gimp opens up with one main window and 2 side window toolbars.

Anyways, when either one of said windows move (get dragged by mouse) I want the other windows to follow the step movements of the dragged window so that they aren't independent of one another.

Also I would like to link them in every way such as closing one closes them all.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: sounds like you should one one of the layouts that support this, not try to manually emulate it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels javafx but I can only get the windows not anything else...

Comment: Adding the [tag:javafx] tag.

Comment: Which `Window` class is your code referring to? `javafx.stage.Window` does not define a `getWindows()` method or a `getTitle()` method.